# Protractor, with isDisplayed() I get NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

In protractor 2.0, I am checking in a `expect()` if one element is displayed. I expect a false, but the weird thing is that I get following error:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("userForm")

My code is:

```
describe('closeModal', function() {
    it('should close the alert that appears after registration.', function(){
        element(by.id('closeAlertModalButton')).click();
        expect(element(by.id('userForm')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

I understand that I get that error because element is not longer on the page (is what I want to confirm), but shouldn't I get a false and not a error?

Comment: You should better use isElementPresent or isPresent - error you've got is part of WebDriver logic

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`isDisplayed()` would check if an element is visible or not, but you need to check whether an element is present in DOM or not, use [`isElementPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.isElementPresent) or [`isPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent):

```
expect(browser.isElementPresent(element(by.id('userForm')))).toBe(false);
expect(element(by.id('userForm')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

See also:

- [How do I test if an img tag exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263505/how-do-i-test-if-an-img-tag-exists)
- [Use element by css to check if element exists in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024342/use-element-by-css-to-check-if-element-exists-in-protractor)

Comment: You're a "protractor angel!" I've learned a lot from your answers here! thank you! @alecxe

Comment: @IdanE and I've learned a lot from your questions! Thank you!

Comment: If i do it in condition. it is not working. ex. `if(browser.isElementPresent(element(by.id('userForm')))`

Comment: @ji-ruh `browser.isElementPresent(element(by.id('userForm'))` returns a promise which is always "truthy". You should explicitly resolve the promise to check the actual presence value.

Answer (score 2):

This error is part of WebDriver behavior. For such cases you should better use 
[isPresent](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) or [isElementPresent](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent)

Answer (score 2):

If element visible do A if not visible do B, disregard exception if element not found:

```
element.isDisplayed().then(function(visible){
    if (visible) {
        // do A when element visible
    }else{
        // do B when element not visible 
    }
}, function () {
    //suppress exception if element is not found on page
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.isDisplayed()` assumes the element is present (exists in the DOM)

so if you do

```
expect($('[ng-show=saving]').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

but the element is not present, then instead of graceful failed expectation, `$('[ng-show=saving]').isDisplayed()` will throw an error causing the rest of `it` block not executed

### Solution

If you assume, the element you're checking may not be present for any reason on the page, then go with a safe way below

```
/**
*  element is Present and is Displayed
*  @param    {ElementFinder}      $element       Locator of element
*  @return   {boolean}
*/
let isDisplayed = function ($element) {
  return (await $element.isPresent()) && (await $element.isDisplayed())
}
```

and use

```
expect(await isDisplayed( $('[ng-show=saving]') )).toBe(true);
```